# Print the whole content in an HTML frame using chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html

There exists chrome plugins for capture the whole page, not just the currently visible part, like creen-capture-by-google. But that doesn't work with page having frames. I need the whole content in the frame saved as PDF or PNG. Is there anyway to do that with Chrome or other browsers? I'm using Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

You could load the frame itself into a tab, and then use one of the plugins to capture the entire frame that way.

Comment: The problem is the frame is dynamically generated and when I load it into a separate tab, I have a Gone Permanently problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use Safari to do this. Right-click in the frame you want to print. Choose Print Frame from the contextual menu. When the print dialog comes up, choose Save as PDF from the PDF pop-up menu in the lower left corner of the dialog pane.